# Translating Roman numerals into Arabic ones

Tags: math, integer, prolog, converters, roman-numerals

I have built a predicate, which converts Roman numerals into Arabic ones. The only problem is that the predicate is limited: if I want to convert more than 3 Arabic numerals at once it does not work anymore.

This is how the predicate should work:

```
?- convert([v,i,i],Arabic).
Arabic = 7.
```

My solution so far:

```
tran([],0).
tran(i,1).
tran(v,5).
tran(x,10).

convert([],X) :- X is 0, !.
convert([T],X) :- tran(T,E), X is E,!.
convert([T|Ts],X) :- tran(T,E), tran(Ts,Es), X is E+Es,!.
convert([T,Ts,Tss],X) :- tran(T,E), tran(Ts,Es), tran(Tss,Ess), X is E+Es+Ess.
```

I know why the predicate does not work with more than 3 numerals and I could also expand the convert-predicate, but with the same pattern as shown above.

How can I make the convert-predicate more "general" (so that it could work independently of the number of numerals)? Or do you have other ideas how to write the predicate?
Thanks :)

Comment: Some comments and hints. You can simplify `convert([],X) :-...` to `convert([],0).` and `convert([T],X) :- ...` to `convert([T],E) :- tran(T,E).` Note that the rules for Roman numerals (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) depend upon whether a higher value follows a lower value. So your `convert` predicate will need to look at two consecutive values to make a choice, *e.g.* `convert([X,Y|T], Value) :- X < Y, % add in Y-X`. I would also recommend converting the list to numbers first, then operating to simplify arithmetic and comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this too much, but I've tried it on several numbers and it seems to work.

The code obeys "subtractive pair rule", described, for example, at https://projecteuler.net/about=roman_numerals

The code uses "accumulator" technique to pass information what was the sum of digits seen before. Initial call just sets the accumulator to 0.

```
digit(i, 1).
digit(v, 5).
digit(x, 10).
digit(l, 50).
digit(c, 100).
digit(d, 500).
digit(m, 1000).

convert(Roman, Arabic) :-
    convert(Roman, 0, Arabic).

convert([], Acc, Acc).

convert([A], Acc, Arabic) :-
    digit(A, AVal),
    Arabic is Acc + AVal.

convert([A, B | Rest], Acc, Arabic) :-
    digit(A, AVal), digit(B, BVal),
    AVal < BVal,
    NewAcc is Acc + BVal - AVal,
    convert(Rest, NewAcc, Arabic).

convert([A, B | Rest], Acc, Arabic) :-
    digit(A, AVal), digit(B, BVal),
    AVal >= BVal,
    NewAcc is Acc + AVal,
    convert([B | Rest], NewAcc, Arabic).
```

Some tests:

```
convert([v, i, i], Arabic).
Arabic = 7 

?- convert([x, i, x], Arabic).
Arabic = 19 

?- convert([m, d, c, v, i], Arabic).
Arabic = 1606
```

It's probably possible to write a predicate `convert` that works both ways in true Prolog spirit using constraint programming, but I haven't tried this approach.

Comment: That's basically the approach I was thinking of. A minor variation would be to call `maplist(digit, Roman, Numbers)` in the `convert/2` predicate, then run the `convert/3` on `Numbers`, eliminating the individual `digit/2` queries.

Answer (score 3):

It might help if you consider the number of discrete "digits" in the Roman numbering system is more than just I, X and V, viz:

```
roman( "M"   , 1000 ) .
roman( "CM"  ,  900 ) .
roman( "D"   ,  500 ) .
roman( "CD"  ,  400 ) .
roman( "C"   ,  100 ) .
roman( "XC"  ,   90 ) .
roman( "L"   ,   50 ) .
roman( "XL"  ,   40 ) .
roman( "X"   ,   10 ) .
roman( "IX"  ,    9 ) .
roman( "V"   ,    5 ) .
roman( "IV"  ,    4 ) .
roman( "I"   ,    1 ) .
```

Then you can write something like

```
roman_to_decimal( R , D ) :-
  roman_to_decimal( R , 0 , D )
  .

roman_to_decimal( [] , D , D ) :- .
roman_to_decimal( R  , T , D ) :-
  roman(P,V) ,
  append(P,S,R) ,
  ! ,
  T1 is T+V ,
  roman_to_decimal(S,T1,D)
  .
```

Invoke it as

```
roman_to_decimal( "MCM" , D ) .
```

This does have some shortcomings, to whit:

- It doesn't enforce syntax: the Roman numbering system required the discrete components to be ordered left-to-right in descending order of value. This doesn't take that into consideration.
- It doesn't take into account the many variations. Should 999 be represented as the compact **IM** or as the rather more verborse **CMXCIX**?

Comment: Your second bullet isn't, strictly speaking, an issue since according to the description of Roman Numerals, a form like "IM" isn't really valid. There are only a few specific cases called out in Roman Numeral subtractive notation.

Comment: Actual Roman usage was rather more flexible than modern convention allows: "CCCCC" and "D" were both perfectly valid ways to indicate 500. Just to complicate things, Roman usage in its heyday also included large value support -- a *macron* (horizontal bar) over a "digit" scaled it by 1000 (M-with-macron = 1,000,000, V-with-macron = 5,000, etc.) Regularity is for wimps!

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of that. I rather like the approach. A couple other comments: (1) Needs terminal case `roman_to_decimal([], D, D).`, (2) `roman(S,T1,D)` should be `roman_to_decimal(S,T1,D)` I assume, (3) it needs a cut, or `roman_to_decimal("MCM", D")` will yield `1900` and `2100` as solutions.

Comment: Typos fixed. I remember some stuff from my high school Latin classes :D

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a variant to the mix, this version uses the scheme in Sergey's answer (which also allows more arbitrary subtractive sequences), and allows a more human-readable input like Nicholas' answer.

```
numeral('I', 1).
numeral('V', 5).
numeral('X', 10).
numeral('L', 50).
numeral('C', 100).
numeral('D', 100).
numeral('M', 1000).

r2n(R, N) :-
    char_code(A, R),
    lower_upper(A, C),
    numeral(C, N).

trans(R, N) :-
    maplist(r2n, R, Rn),    % Pre-calculate a numeric list representation
    trans(Rn, 0, N).
trans([X,Y|T], Acc, N) :-
    X >= Y,
    Acc1 is Acc + X,
    trans([Y|T], Acc1, N).
trans([X,Y|T], Acc, N) :-
    X < Y,
    Acc1 is Acc - X,
    trans([Y|T], Acc1, N).
trans([X], Acc, N) :-
    N is Acc + X.
trans([], N, N).   % Optional rule: needed only if you want trans("", 0). to succeed
```

Note these rules will allow any valid Roman numeral, but will also do something with and succeed on some improperly formed Roman numerals. So it is not a set of rules to validate proper Roman numerals.

Sample output:

```
| ?- trans("mmxiv", X).

X = 2014 ? ;

no
| ?- trans("CMXCIX", X).

X = 999 ? ;

no
| ?- trans("IM", X).

X = 999 ? ;

no
| ?- trans("IVX", X).   % Not a properly-formed Roman numeral

X = 4 ? ;   % Uh... ok... I guess

no
```